# Copying & pasting multiple values from one feature to other features in the same layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, features, copy, paste

I have added some features to my layer and want to copy-paste certain values from certain columns to the newly added features.
Have a look at the image. The values of the feature at the bottom should be copied and pasted into the three features above.

[image]

At the moment I copy and paste each single value which is a lot of clicking. Is there a way to at least copy-paste the values per column? I imagine it in the way as in Excel, where you can drag a value just by pulling the one cell with a certain value down and it automatically updates the fields which are in the pulled area.
But of course, if there is another way, I would be glad to hear about it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is the **AttributePainter** plugin (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/attributePainter/) for this.

Usage:

1. Click on <kbd>Pick source feature</kbd> and select a sample feature on the map.
2. On the table, a selection list for attributes will appear.
3. Check the attributes to be copied.
4. Use <kbd>Pick to Apply</kbd> to copy one by one
5. Or select destination features and use <kbd>Apply to selection</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Oh, this looks very helpful! I will try it out! Thank you!

Comment: This works exactly as I hoped for! Many thanks!